# Method going to second returning, resulting in false output

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, tree-traversal

I'm trying to find a specific node in a binary tree using Java. My method for finding the node returns the node that contains the data that was searched for.

My code looks like this:

```
    public BinNode find(Comparable item) throws NullPointerException {
        if (item == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("item is NULL");
        } else if (root == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("tree is empty");
        }
        return find(root, item);
    }

    public static boolean found = false;
    public BinNode find(BinNode k, Comparable item) throws NullPointerException {
        if (k.getData().equals(item)) {
            found = true;
            return k;
        }
        if (!found && k.getChildLeft() != null) {
            find(k.getChildLeft(), item);
        }
        if (!found && k.getChildRight() != null) {
            find(k.getChildRight(), item);
        }
        return k;
    }
```

Running the debugger I can see, that when I search for an item that exists in the tree, it will find the correct node and go to the first return statement after "found" is set to true.
However, then compiler doesn't return that Node to the method call, but goes on to the second return statement, returning the root. So no matter where the Node is located, the method will always return the root.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `public static boolean found = false;` do you really need that to be a class member?

Comment: Thank you, my mistake, I do not!

Answer (score 1):

Your method never returns "not found" which is fundamentally wrong because most of the times an item is not in the data. And that is your main problem. You need to return `null` / an empty `Optional` in the bottom `return` statement. And then you need to properly handle that "not found" return value when traversing the tree downwards, namely where you call `find` for the left and right child.

Your logic has to always be:

- has the current node the correct value

  - if yes return the current node
- does the left node contain the value

  - if yes return the corresponding node from the left
- does the right node contain the value

  - if yes return the corresponding node from the right
- return "not found" (because the current node is not correct and neither the left nor the right contain the value)

You currently skip / have not implemented the two nested "if yes return the corresponding node from the left/right" code paths.

(and of course remove the `found` variable as noted in a comment)

---

```
public BinNode find(BinNode k, Comparable item) throws NullPointerException {
    if (k.getData().equals(item)) {
        return k;
    }
    if (k.getChildLeft() != null) {
        BinNode node = find(k.getChildLeft(), item);
        if (node != null) return node;
    }
    if (k.getChildRight() != null) {
        BinNode node = find(k.getChildRight(), item);
        if (node != null) return node;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The return type of the method must be BinNode - is it okay to return null, if the value was not found?

Comment: @Agnetha returning `null` is not ideal but *okay*.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time, I hope you don't mind my asking, but what *would* be the ideal solution?

Comment: @Agnetha using `Optional<BinNode>` as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the finds from the left and right calls.

Your code finds the node and returns the k, but the other finds make no returns so your code continues on with code after the conditional statements, which is to return the node k.  However, this falls back through the return stack to the original call to the double argument find, which has root as the BinNode given, so that is what is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Refer Luk2302 answer.
You forgot "return" for left and right calls for find() function.

```
if (!found && k.getChildLeft() != null) {
       return find(k.getChildLeft(), item);
}
if (!found && k.getChildRight() != null) {
       return find(k.getChildRight(), item);
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the node is found in the right node because the code will always check the left first and return.

Comment: Luk2302 is right, it fixed my first test, but it does not work for a node thats in the right subtree